# How do i edit the configuration of Prometheus stack deployed to Kubernetes using a helm chart?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I am working for an organization and they have a prometheus monitoring helm chart consisiting of Prometheus, Grafana, Node Exporter and Kube Stat Metrics. My job is to configure alertmanager from scratch.

I was able to configure alertmanager from scratch but I am having trouble editing the Prometheus configuration so that prometheus can talk to alertmanager and send alerts to alertmanager.

So, how do i edit the configuration of prometheus ?

I tried adding a `static_configs`  field to the `alerting` section of prometheus config but it gave me a validation error and said `static_configs is an unknown field` . I guess that happened because the template from which prometheus helm chart was installed, did not contain a `static_configs` field.

Any suggestions or advice on how i can edit prometheus config and add alertmanager as an endpoint would really help.